# Уникальный номер устройства, который Apple разрешает использовать и который остается уникальным при переустановки приложения

Tags: ios, xcode

Могу ли я использовать этот код в приложении, в котором не используются баннеры и отсутствует какая-либо реклама? (слышал, что Apple реджектит приложения, которые без рекламы собирают статистику номеров девайсов).

Так же я не просто хочу хранить уникальный номер в кейчейн, а отправлять его на сервер для сравнения в БД.

```
-(NSString *)getUniqueDeviceIdentifierAsString
{

 NSString *appName=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleNameKey];

 NSString *strApplicationUUID = [SSKeychain passwordForService:appName account:@"incoding"];

 if (strApplicationUUID == nil)
 {
     strApplicationUUID  = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];
     [SSKeychain setPassword:strApplicationUUID forService:appName account:@"incoding"];
 }

 return strApplicationUUID;
}
```

Политика Apple постоянно меняется в этом направлении, поэтому хотелось бы узнать - какой на текущий момент есть способ идентифицировать девайс пользователя. Нужно чтобы он был таким же и после переустановки приложения.

Меняется ли длина UUID или она равна 32 (не включая "-") у всех девайсов Apple?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код вполне рабочий, но я бы посоветовал сделать 2 вещи:

1. перед чтением из keychain вызывать `[SSKeychain setAccessibilityType:kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlock]` - иначе можно напороться на ситуацию, когда при попытке чтения из keychain будет возвращён nil, если на устройстве включен Touch ID. Очень хорошо сабж описан [здесь](https://www.progressconcepts.com/blog/keychain-app-state-ios/)
2. сохранить первое чтение из кейчейна в `static` переменную и читать из неё, если будет больше 1 вызова метода - это сильно сократит время чтения, потому что чтение из keychain может заметно затянуться и обращение к нему в основной очереди может дать ощутимый лаг.

Вообще, достаточно будет сложить в keychain любую строку, например гуид и работать с ним не боясь что apple в будущем снова изменит правила игры

Comment: Решил не брать UUID устройства (ходят слухи, что его нельзя использовать в приложениях без показа рекламы. Apple считает, что я хочу собрать статистику... а зачем?!), а просто генерить 32 значный случайный код, который записываю в keychain.